# Can I get Maven to print out a custom error message when SQL plugin fails to connect to db?

Tags: mysql, maven, error-handling, maven-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3, MySQL 5.5 with the Maven SQL plugin (v 1.5) to create a test database for my JUnit testing ...

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                            <version>5.1.18</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://${test.mysql.db.host}:${test.mysql.db.port}/${test.mysql.db.sid}</url>
                        <username>${test.mysql.db.user}</username>
                        <password>${test.mysql.db.password}</password>
                        <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                        <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-test-db</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <url>jdbc:mysql://${test.mysql.db.host}:${test.mysql.db.port}</url>
                                <username>${test.mysql.db.user}</username>
                                <password>${test.mysql.db.password}</password>
                                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                <sqlCommand>create database if not exists ${test.mysql.db.sid}</sqlCommand>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
```

If the connection can't be made (because the user hasn't been created or has the wrong privileges), I'd like to display a friendlier error message than what is printed out by default when things die.  Does anyone know how to do that?  I'm open to using other plugins besides the Maven SQL plugin.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

Since the error messages are specific to each database (you would get a different error message on Oracle than on MySQL), and each database handles these errors in a different manner, there's probably not a generic approach. The Spring framework encapsulates database errors into a rich exception hierarchy, you might want to take a look at that to see how they're handling these errors in a generic manner.

One option is to extend the Maven SQL Plugin and add that functionality in there. If you can do it in a generic manner across databases, even better, but I guess if you could make it work just for MySQL, that would already help you.

Any specific reason why you want to provide friendlier error messages?

Comment: I want to provide friendlier error messages so other developers running the pom know EXACTLY what to do when it fails.  We will always be using MySQL if that helps answer this question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a Wiki page listing common error messages, what they mean and how to fix them?

Comment: Unfortunately, no one reads emails or wiki pages.  As I said I want to make this painfully easy so that as soon as they see the error message, they know exactly what to do without having to read anything or visit any external web sites.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? If so can you share it with others, I'm in need of the same. I know it's a very old thread, still if you got the answer kindly post